# Best way to send huge amount of e-mails in PHP

Tags: php, email, newsletter

I have a big amount of users that agreed to recive daily newsletter. Content of newsletter is being auto-generated, so the only thing to do is to set up a cron job which would send e-mails.

However, if there is e.g. 10.000 users, such cron job would kill my server. What can be done to solve this problem?

Is sleep(1) after sending 100 e-mails enough? (and of course setting execution time limit to 1 day)

Comment: I would use a mail service like [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) to do large jobs

Answer (score 4):

Have a look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

> Note:
>
> It is worth noting that the mail() function is not suitable for larger
>   volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP
>   socket for each email, which is not very efficient.
>
> For the sending of large amounts of email, see the » PEAR::Mail, and »
>   PEAR::Mail_Queue packages.

So simply use the Mail_Queue package... which takes every mail and then simply works through them.

Answer (score 3):

I have made a system for sending emails for project few months ago so I done the following:

In database, I have 3 tables:

users
user_emails (some users have multiple emails)
email_campaign (this is table in which I store data temporary while sending campaign and on finish I truncate everything in it)

And when I start sending campaign I insert row in email_campaign table for every user that I finished sending email to.
This way if error occur before campaign finishes, I know where to continue and know to whom I sent email and to who need to send email.

Practicaly I was able to send 45.000 emails during 2 hours. Without server overload.
I use sleep() on every 100 emails like you wanted to do.
Also I send campaigns at 2 am in the morning when my server load is the lowest.

You could also configure your email server to send limited ammount of emails per hour.
This would slow sending but it will reduce server load.